# Tool to edit CSS from script (better than `sed`)

Tags: shell-script, command, software-rec

I need to modify CSS file from a script and I want to make sure I don't break it.

Is there any command line tool that understands CSS structures and allows to edit them?

TLDR; I need `jq` command but for CSS files, a command line CSS parser/editor.

Comment: Are you going to reinvent sass?

Comment: all I want is to edit a css file automatically but without worrying about breaking it

Comment: Then look into sass.

Comment: I don't really see how `sass` helps here... Could you elaborate on how I could achieve this with `sass`?

Comment: oh, did you meant to convert it to scss and then work with sass on it and compile into css? I look into it

Comment: I've looked and while I could override style from that css I can't really modify them, so it doesn't really help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `csso-cli` or 'csso'.

Run `npm install -g csso-cli`.